# Libreoffice-Calc: Count number of rows and ouput total below list

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to write a macro that counts the number of columns that contain data and prints the result at the bottom of the list?

For example, if the data is:

```
|1|2|3|
|a| | |
|1| |3|
```

The final table would be:

```
|1|2|3|
|a| | |
|1| |3|
|=|=|=|
|3|1|2|
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different approaches:

- Use [**`COUNTIF()`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Mathematical_Functions#COUNTIF), comparing the rows range with an empty string:

  > `=COUNTIF(A1:A3;"<>''")`
- use [**`COUNTBLANK()`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Mathematical_Functions#COUNTBLANK) and subtract the result from the sum of rows:

  > `=ROWS(A1:A3)-COUNTBLANK(A1:A3)`

In both cases, just enter the formula in A4 and drag it to the right, LO Calc will adapt the cell references automatically.